# Handling server errors in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, error-handling

I have a error page, so that whenever there is a server error I redirect the page to error.aspx. So when I tested it by removing a parameter from the code, the code fails and it should redirect to error.aspx instead it is still showing the server error in the same page. How should I redirect the page when there is a server error. I have the custom error in my web config

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The MySqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null MySqlParameter type objects.
Parameter name: value

<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="error.aspx">
</customErrors>
```

I have a datalayer where all the db queries are done.

Comment: How did you get on? Does it work now?

Answer (score 1):

```
mode="RemoteOnly
```

means you'll not use the Custom error page unless it is viewed remotely. Change it to `On` if you want to see the custom error page from localhost.

This is taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx):

**mode** - Specifies whether custom errors are enabled, disabled, or shown only to remote clients.

This attribute can be one of the following values.

**On** - Specifies that custom errors are enabled. If no defaultRedirect attribute is specified, users see a generic error. The custom errors are shown to the remote clients and to the local host.

**Off** - Specifies that custom errors are disabled. The detailed ASP.NET errors are shown to the remote clients and to the local host.

**RemoteOnly** - Specifies that custom errors are shown only to the remote clients, and that ASP.NET errors are shown to the local host. This is the default value.

The default is RemoteOnly.